# How can I extract an int, from (int, int) format variable? It says I can't use indexing

Tags: c#, variables, formatting

I'm working on a NeuralNet and I decided to store the edges (connections) of the network in format `(int,int) edge`.
I used it because it's very easy to add it to a list `List<(int,int)> listOfConnections`

I've already implemented this variable in multiple places in my code and only now I've realized I'm not sure how to access each int separately.
When I try `edge[0]` i get an error that I can't use indexing in this type of variable.

Any ideas how can I pull out the first and second ints separately?
Also what's the name of this form of variable? It's not Touple, not a Vector, if I knew the name maybe I could find more information on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-6.0).

You can access the first item with `edge.Item1` and the second with `edge.Item2`.

[.NET Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/urfah9)

Answer (score 2):

Tuples don't support indexing in C#. To access individual members in tuples, use the following syntax:

```
(int, int) edge = (3, 8)
Console.Writeline(edge.Item1) // 3
Console.Writeline(edge.Item2) // 8
```

Alternatively, you can name the tuple members for better readability:

```
(int foo, int bar) edge = (3, 8)
Console.Writeline(edge.foo) // 3
Console.Writeline(edge.bar) // 8
```

Or use tuple unpacking:

```
(int foo, int bar) = (3, 8)
Console.Writeline(foo) // 3
Console.Writeline(bar) // 8
```

Comment: Cool methods! Thanks so much. Especially practical seems the ability to name the members.

Answer (score 1):

So you've a list full of ValueTuple:

```
var edge = (1, 2);
var var listOfConnections = new List<(int, int)>();
```

Each item is an `(int, int)`, and like Broots says, has an `Item1` and `Item2`..

```
listOfConnections[0].Item1
```

..but if you give your tuple names in the List declaration:

```
var listOfConnections = new List<(int Prev, int Next)>();
```

..you can use those names:

```
listOfConnections[0].Prev
```

Or if you  want to give them different names, regardless of what their current names are, you can define the tuple as having different names in the variable signature:

```
List<(int Start, int End)> someList = listOfConnections;

someList[0].Start;
```

Or if you want to dig the ValueTuple out with different names declare the "type" of the variable as a different signature with regard to the names:

```
(int Go, int Stop) x = listOfConnections[0];
x.Go;
```

Or if you want to deconstruct the ValueTuple inside the list to a pair of variables, give a type signature for the variable but don't give a name for the variable:

```
(int node1, int node2) = listOfConnections[0];

Console.Write(a); //node1 is an int variable like any other, e.g. var node1 = 1;
```

---

The whole thing with ValueTuples and naming the members is really flexible because it's all just syntactic sugar added by the compiler. They're just `(int, int)` and the names you use depends on the most-recently-given definition for the context:

```
public List<(int Foo, int Bar)> GetNodes(){
  return ...
}

var x = GetNodes();                             //x[0].Foo
List<(int Baz, int Bop)> y = GetNodes();        //y[0].Baz
var z = (List<(int Bob, int Ben)>)GetNodes();   //z[0].Bob
```

---

**Just remember** - if you're serializing these things to e.g. JSON, they *only have names in the context of your source code*. By the time they're compiled everything is just called Item1, Item2 so they'll serialize as that. The knowledge of what your source code called them is gone..